# How to register more than 100 Plugins in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework-mvc

My system needs to register more than 100 plugins, but after 100 Zend Framework simply cut the rest of. Is there a limitation on the number of plugins that can be registered? Has somebody an idea where I can setup this plugin limitation?
If there is no such limitation, what else could be the problem?

Comment: How do you know it stops exactly at the 101st plugin? Any errors in the 101st plugin?

Comment: Which version of Zend do you use?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest - if you have 99 plugins, than something is wrong. But even though - i don't think, that there is such limit. There might be a plugin with offset 100. Which might break something. Try dumping the plugins array...

Comment: Some classes like the ViewRenderer and the layout resource - and I think even the error handler - function as plugins with high stack-index (in the area of 100, I believe). So, it seems at least possible that one of these is interfering with your own custom plugins. Still, I agree with @Tomáš Fejfar: it sounds pretty unusual to have that many plugins in an app.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any limitation to an arbitrary number of plugins in [the sources](http://framework.zend.com/code/filedetails.php?repname=Zend+Framework&path=%2Ftrunk%2Flibrary%2FZend%2FController%2FPlugin%2FBroker.php) (look for registerPlugin()), are you sure you're not trying to include the same plugin twice ?

Answer (score 0):

An option is that it's the recursing that kicks out saying it's an infinite loop. At my work some spaghetti code recursed the same function exactly 100 times. I use xdebug, and that plugin thinks at exactly the 100th recurse that: "ok, this is infinite, give fatal". It really sucked tracking that down. I just changed it to 99, lol

Anyway, you will be better off making a model, then loading that model in one plugin and letting that model load all the other plugins, like a service layer of sorts.